# How to call `ng add` of library in custom `ng new`

Tags: angular-schematics

I have a workspace including two angular libraries with `ng add` schematics and a schematics project with a custom `ng new` schematic.

I'd like to call the `ng add` schematics of the libraries from my `ng new` schematic, so I don't have to maintain their setup in two places.

Unfortunately this seems impossible because the `externalSchematics` function requires the collection to be available which makes calling `ng add` kind of pointless.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the library with the `ng add` schematic as a dependency of the schematics project should actually let you call `externalSchematics('library', 'ng-add', options)` from the custom `ng new`.

Unfortunately there is a regression bug and this doesn't work since the change to Angular 9: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18098.